# My question is about getting a solution to calculate the total price of an order with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developping a web page were there is some products in their prices and the quantity of each one, what I'm trying to do, is to calculate the total price, but, with the same class name for every product

I've already tried the solution in the code bellow, but I'm not getting the right price

```
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="../img/produit_newyork_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">New York City</p>
                <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">1</span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="../img/produit_londres_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">Londres City</p>
                <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">3</span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript>

         const qte =  document.querySelectorAll('.qte');
         const prix = document.querySelectorAll('.prix');
         const prixPanier = document.querySelector('#prixPanier');
         const TVA = document.querySelector('#TVA');
         const Total = document.querySelector('#Total');

         let prixTotal = 0;

         for(let i=0; i < qte.length; i++){
             prixTotal = prixTotal + (parseInt(qte[i].innerText)*                                                 parseFloat(prix[i].innerText));
         }

         prixPanier.innerText = prixTotal;
         TVA.innerText = prixTotal * 0.15;

        </script>
```

So what I'm looking for, is the right solution also for my last question, How can i add the total and the TVA so i can get the final or the total price ?

Comment: You should probably be using `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`, for one thing.

Comment: What price are you getting now?

Comment: `const prixPanier = document.querySelector('#prixPanier');` is undefined from the code you provided

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz i'm getting 196 €

Comment: @YannickK which part ? html or js ? because i didn't post the part of code where i print the results

Comment: @Pointy I tried, i'm getting NaN as result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with numbers that contain symbols that are not detected or parsed with JavaScript internal functions, you should make sure to avoid those problems by simply removing the symbol before parsing anything.

This is how the code working looks like:

```
for(let i=0; i < qte.length; i++){
    let price = parseFloat(prix[i].innerText.replace('€','').replace(',','.')),
        quantity = parseInt(qte[i].innerText);
    prixTotal += (quantity*price);
}
```

Also, it has kind of a better readability. I'll leave you a
Fiddle so you can check if it is giving your desired output:

https://jsfiddle.net/y0x84rwq/

Comment: Thank you, so my solution working it's just i made some mistakes ?

Comment: any way, thank you, im getting the right number now.

Comment: Glad to help you. It's a common issue that we forget about how JavaScript functions parse data, so you just need to keep in mind this when working with numbers that are strings.

Comment: @k3lly.dev `parseFloat("123.45xyz")` will ignore the trailing "xyz" and produce no error. The comma, however, is a problem.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for pointing it out, didn't knew about that.. So the € symbol would count as xyz?

Comment: @k3lly.dev yes, it's a weird feature that might have something to do with parsing things like style attribute values ("102.5px") but that is just my personal theory. It could also just be an old dumb idea that can't be taken away for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues:

- the price contain comma, need convert to dot before use.

  **let price = parseFloat(prix[i].innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '.')).toFixed(2);**

This is worked code:

```js
const qte =  document.querySelectorAll('.qte');
         const prix = document.querySelectorAll('.prix');
         const prixPanier = document.querySelector('#prixPanier');
         const TVA = document.querySelector('#TVA');
         const Total = document.querySelector('#Total');

         let prixTotal = 0.0;

         for(let i=0; i < qte.length; i++){
             let price = parseFloat(prix[i].innerText.replace(/,/g, '.')).toFixed(2);
             //console.log(price)
             prixTotal = prixTotal + (parseInt(qte[i].innerHTML)*                                                 price);
         }

         prixPanier.innerText = prixTotal;
         TVA.innerText = prixTotal * 0.15;
```

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="../img/produit_newyork_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">New York City</p>
                <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">1</span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="../img/produit_londres_0.jpeg" class="img-fluid float-left mr-5" width="80" height="60"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <p class="mb-auto">Lego Architecture</p>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">Londres City</p>
                <p class="font-italic">Quantité : <span class="qte">3</span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 class="text-right prix">49,99€</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right">Supprimer <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div id="prixPanier"></div>
        <div id="TVA"></div>
```

Comment: Why innerHTML instead of innerText?

Comment: same question as @k3lly.dev